# CMake: Undefined reference to OrganizedMultiPlaneSegmentation

Tags: point-cloud-library

I'm trying to use PCL's organized_multi_plane_segmentation. But when I compile, I hit this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/multiplane.dir/multiplane.cpp.o: in function `main':
multiplane.cpp:(.text+0x41d): undefined reference to `pcl::OrganizedMultiPlaneSegmentation<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::PointNormal, pcl::PointXYZL>::segment(std::vector<pcl::ModelCoefficients, std::allocator<pcl::ModelCoefficients> >&, std::vector<pcl::PointIndices, std::allocator<pcl::PointIndices> >&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/multiplane.dir/build.make:192: multiplane] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:76: CMakeFiles/multiplane.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

It only has an issue with the segment function, because when I run it without segment, the code compiles fine. I can't tell what I'm doing incorrectly within that line.

Code I'm running is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pcl/ModelCoefficients.h>
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <pcl/visualization/cloud_viewer.h>
#include <pcl/sample_consensus/method_types.h>
#include <pcl/sample_consensus/model_types.h>
#include <pcl/segmentation/sac_segmentation.h>
#include <pcl/filters/passthrough.h>
#include <pcl/filters/extract_indices.h>
#include <pcl/common/common.h>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <pcl/segmentation/organized_multi_plane_segmentation.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>)

    std::string filename (argv[1]);
    // std::cout << filename << std::endl;

    multiplanesegment.setInputCloud(cloud);
    std::vector<pcl::ModelCoefficients> model_coefficients;
    std::vector<pcl::PointIndices> inlier_indices;
    multiplanesegment.segment(model_coefficients,inlier_indices);

    return 0;
}
```

My CMakeLists is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5 FATAL_ERROR)
project(multiplane_test)

find_package(PCL 1.7 REQUIRED)

include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})

add_executable(multiplane multiplane.cpp)
target_link_libraries(multiplane ${PCL_LIBRARIES})
```

I'm on ubuntu 20.04, PCL ver 1.10, compiling through cmake on visual studio. I've been looking for a fix for hours, but as far as I can tell the issue is in my use of this particular function, and I can't find any working examples online.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to use `OrganizedMultiPlaneSegmentation` with `pcl::PointXYZL` as the third template parameter. PCL contains explicit instantiations of the classes, but `OrganizedMultiPlaneSegmentation` is only instantiated with `pcl::Label` as the third template parameter (see https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/master/segmentation/src/organized_multi_plane_segmentation.cpp#L44). You can put `#define PCL_NO_PRECOMPILE` before including the headers (see https://pcl.readthedocs.io/projects/tutorials/en/master/adding_custom_ptype.html), then the templated classes will be instantiated when you build your program, for any point types you want.